# How to sort a range based on non-empty cells in each row?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

As it's shown in the image, rows in the range with **highest number of non-empty cells** move to the top position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code that will sort the way you explain.

```
Sub SortByCountA()
    ' 136
    
    Dim Ws      As Worksheet
    Dim Rng     As Range
    Dim C       As Long                 ' helper column
    
    Set Ws = Worksheets(1)              ' change to suit
    With Ws.UsedRange
        C = .Columns.Count + 1
        Set Rng = .Resize(, C)
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Rng
        .Cells(.Row, C).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(RC[" & (1 - C) & "]:RC[-1])"
        .Columns(C).FillDown
    End With
        
    With Ws.Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add2 Key:=Ws.Cells(Rng.Row, C), _
                  SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                  Order:=xlDescending, _
                  DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        .SetRange Rng
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
    Ws.Columns(C).EntireColumn.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The difficulty in this task is to define the range that needs to be sorted. The above code sorts the entire `UsedRange`. It doesn't expewct to encounter any tables and it expects to start in column A. The `Sort.Header` property is set to *xlNo*. An easy modification would be to set it to *xlYes*. If you have a more difficult range it isn't difficult to adapt the above code to work with such a range once it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

In Output table `E2`, formula copied across and down :

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/INDEX(A$2:A$5,MATCH(IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$2:$A$5/($B$2:$B$5<>""),ROW(A1)),AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$2:$A$5/($B$2:$B$5=""),COUNT($A$2:$A$5)-COUNT(E$1:E1))),$A$2:$A$5,0))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain you formula?

Comment: @P.b, the logic is sorted list A by the condition of If list B have data, else sorted list A by the condition of list B haven't data.

Answer (score 0):

`=SORT(SORT(SORT(A1:C4;1;1);2;1);3;1)`
In office 365 you can use sort over sort over sort. It sorts by column A, than column B, then C.

[image: example]